# Automatically uploading text files to an FTP site

Tags: ftp, automation

I'm looking to automate an upload of a text file to an FTP site. This upload would need to occur daily, and I have access to a server that would run whatever script needed to do the upload. I've looked around for a solution to this and found some information on howtogeek, but neither idea there seemed to be automatic. I'm looking to do this without third-party software if possible. I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Why without third party software? What's wrong with a bash script (or windows script)? This sounds like something you could do with a cron job fairly easily.

Comment: I don't have the budget for third party software, and I am unfamiliar with bash/window scripts. I don't have any background in Unix, so cron is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm), there are many ways you could do this though. Try looking around and trying some things and ask again when you get stuck. Windows also has a [software similar to cron](http://ss64.com/nt/at.html).

Comment: What platform? Do I understand right that you want to upload a file from a Unix machine to some FTP server? But you need to initiate the upload from a Windows machine? You question is pretty vague in that respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on windows I'd use vbscript (more functionality can be added easily) or .bat files (if you don't need extra functionality) to call on windows FTP.(Provided you don't need anything super secure) Just build the .bat file to call on FTP and append the connection information accordingly. The link [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-automate-ftp-uploads-from-the-windows-command-line/) should help you out. Now in order to make this automatic you need to use the "Task Scheduler" to schedule how you want the script to run.